# matrix_transformer

Tags: c++, boost

В `boost::geometry` есть алгоритм `transform`, который, используя различные стратегии, позволяет производить афинные преобразования. Меня интересует использование `matrix_transformer` для этих целей. Как я понял, если, к примеру, мне нужно сдвинуть прямоугольник на `x, y` позицию, то для этого нужна матрица вида:

```
namespace bg = boost::geometry;
bg::strategy::transform::matrix_transform<float, 2, 2> trans{1, 0, x, 0, 1, y, 0, 0, 1};
bg::model::box box{/*here two floats points*/};
bg::transform(box, box, trans);
```

Но я бы хотел хранить и видоизменять эту матрицу, например когда измениться позиция, на которую нужно сдвинуть прямоугольник, или если нужно будет его повернуть. Как я могу (и могу ли) получать значения из этой матрицы и изменять их.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matrix_transformer` использует внутри [`boost::qvm::mat`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/qvm/index.html), поэтому можно работать с ним напрямую:

```
namespace bg = boost::geometry;
boost::qvm::mat<float, 3, 3> trans_matr {1, 0, x, 0, 1, y, 0, 0, 1};
// ...
boost::geometry::strategy::transform::matrix_transformer<float, 2, 2> trans{trans_matr};
```

доступ к текущей матрице для всех матричных трансформаций возможен через:

```
trans.matrix();
```

`boost::qvm::mat` в свою очередь может быть преобразован в произвольный матричный тип.

Но если трансформации ограничиваются только, например, сдвигом, то эффективней будет не хранить всю матрицу в течение длительного времени, а конструировать её непосредственно перед использованием:

```
boost::geometry::strategy::transform::translate_transformer<float, 2, 2> trans{x, y};
boost::geometry::transform(box, box, trans);
```

Это даст возможность оптимизатору выкинуть все умножения на нули/единицы и получить итоговый код столь же быстрый, как и прибавление пары координат к каждой точке.

Comment: По поводу последней части - в том то и дело, что трансформации этим не ограничиваются

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, нум, это также применимо и к любой параметрической трансформации с относительно малым числом параметров... для произвольного аффинного преобразования, конечно придётся хранить всю матрицу...